# Why do the changes I make in my working directory not show up in my Docker container?

Tags: docker, parse-platform

I would like to run a test a [parse-dashboard](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard) via Docker, as documented in the readme.

I am getting the error message, "Parse Dashboard can only be remotely accessed via HTTPS." Normally, you can bypass this by adding the line `"allowInsecureHTTP": true` in your parse-dashboard-config.json file. But even if I have added this option to my config file, the same message is displayed.

I tried to edit the config file in the Docker container, whereupon I discovered that none of my local file changes where present in the container. It appeared as though my project was an unmodified version of the code from the github repository.

Why do the changes that I make to the files in my working directory on the host machine not show up in the Docker container?

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it's really confusing, and doesn't seem to relate to the title. Try asking just one question at a time, and maybe provide more specific steps that you've taken so we can understand what the problem is.

Comment: Alright, I will try to do it better next time.

Comment: What commands are you running?

Comment: Did you try accessing it via `https://localhost` instead of `http://localhost`?

Comment: I edited your question for you. This is the question I believe you were trying to ask, but weren't sure how to. Docker does not interact with Git in any way, and was not checking out any code from any Github branches.

Comment: I will try to say it simply.

Comment: I have tried with http://

Comment: Did you try either of the solutions I posted below? Did it work? Leave a comment on one of the answers below if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

> But what it is upload to my docker, it's in fact the config file of my master branch.

It depends:

- what that "docker" is: the official [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/) or a private docker registry?
- how it is uploaded: do you build an image and then use [`docker push`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/), or do you simply do a `git push` back to your GitHub repo?

Basically, if you want to see the right files in your Docker container that you run, you must be sure to run an image you have built ([`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)) after a `Dockerfile` which [`COPY` files](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy) from your current workspace.
If you do a `docker build` from a folder where your Git repo is checked out at the right branch, you will get an image with the right files.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/blob/master/Dockerfile) from the [parse-dashboard](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/) repository you linked uses `ADD . /src`. This is a bad practice (because of the problems you're running into). Here are two different approaches you could take to work around it:

#### Rebuild the Image Each Time

Any time you change *anything* in the working directory (which the Dockerfile `ADD`s to `/src`), you need to rebuild for the change to take effect. The exception to this is `src/Parse-Dashbaord/parse-dashboard-config.json`, which we'll mount in with a volume. The workflow would be nearly identical to the one in the readme:

```
$ docker build -t parse-dashboard .
$ docker run -d -p 8080:4040 -v ./src/Parse-Dashbaord/parse-dashboard-config.json:/src/Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json parse-dashboard
```

#### Use a Volume

If we're going to use a volume to do this, we don't even need the custom Dockerfile shipped with the project. We'll just use the official [Node](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/node/) image, upon which the Dockerfile is based.

In this case, Docker will not run the build process for you, so you should do it yourself on the host machine before starting Docker:

```
$ npm install
$ npm run build
```

Now, we can start the generic Node Docker image, and ask it do serve our project directory.

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:4040 -v ./:/src node:4.7.2 "cd /src && npm run dashboard"
```

Changes will take effect immediately because you mount `./` into the image as a volume. Because it's not done with `ADD`, you don't need to rebuild the image each time. We can use the generic node image because if we're not `ADD`ing a directory and running the build commands, there's nothing our image will do differently than the official one.